# Script keep looping over code for creation of an iframe inside $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

The code below causes the browser to keep loading, and the iframe creation seems to stuck in an infinite loop. If I move the iframe creation part inside a click event e.g. `#save`, the problem will not occur. I need the iframe to be created right after the page is loaded, not sure what I'm missing here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#receiptNum').append(widgetData.processingFormId);

  //iframe creation part 
  $('<iframe>', {
    name: 'myframe',
    id: 'printing',
    width: 100,
    hieght: 100
  }).appendTo('#Mypage');
  //Mypage is a popup window


  window.open('/Forms/PrintPreviewForm/' + widgetData['processingFormId'], "myframe");

  $('#save').click(function() {

    window.open('/Forms/GetFormPdf/' + widgetData['processingFormId']);

  });

  $('#print').click(function() {

    window.open('/Forms/PrintPreviewForm/' + widgetData['processingFormId']);

  });

});
```

Comment: Is this script also on the page that you're opening in the iframe?

Comment: Yes, the page show a popup(#Mypage) that have this iframe

Comment: If the contents of the iframe also have this script then that will cause an infinite loop. Every time the page inside the iframe loads it will create a new iframe and load that page in it.

Comment: What's a good function other than document ready  I can use to make sure the it's execute only one time